# Insert multiple error with odbc

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc, visual-foxpro

I'm using Codeigniter and my database is VFP, i use odbc to connect to the db.

I tried with odbc_exec instead of code igniter odbc driver.

When i try to execute a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (field1, field2) VALUES (1, 'myValue'), (2, 'anotherValue')
```

i've got a SQL error.

```
Message: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect
```

Inserting one by one is working. But i have to insert more than 20.000 rows and can take ages. Maybe there is an alternate syntax or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Alternate syntax is the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbf_name [(FieldName1 [, FieldName2, ...])] SELECT SELECTClauses [UNION UnionClause SELECT SELECTClauses ...]
```

If you need to insert the data from another dataset, then you can use this syntax. Otherwise, I don't see difference between manual inserting with

```
INSERT INTO myBable (field1, field2) VALUES (1, 'myValue'), (2, 'anotherValue')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO myBable (field1, field2) VALUES (1, 'myValue')
INSERT INTO myBable (field1, field2) VALUES (2, 'anotherValue')
```

Comment: @CarlosGoce, Oleg is correct on his final part.  VFP and dbase in general do not support a comma list for inserts for multiple values.  His last showing two individual insert commands is what will work.